# How to use iPhone with iOS 5 for development?

Tags: iphone, ios5

I have upgraded my iPhone Os to iOS 5 and now it doesn't appear in Xcode-4.0.2 devices list. I can't use it as development phone. XCode organizer tells me to downgrade OS to 4.3! Still I am able to sync App using latest itunes 10.5 but not able to debug my app. Could anyone please tell me what should I do? Is there anyway to use iPhone with iOS 5 as Development phone?

Thanks.

Comment: I use my OS5 iPhone as a dev device with debugging. Are you on the latest XCode?
I'm on Build 4D199

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer.

Comment: Which version of Xcode are you using ? In the menu, go to "Xcode -> About Xcode" and look for the build number.

Comment: True, but updating to Xcode 4.2 (4D199) will allow you to use an iOS 5 device.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Upgrade to Xcode 4.2, which can be found at [developer.apple.com.](http://developer.apple.com)

Comment: After doing this, I needed to go to Organizer and click 'Use For Development' on the device again.